# How do I get calendar alerts to display before the event begins?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, google-calendar

I use Google Calendar a lot for work. On my PC I get alerts appearing 10 mins before an event starts, which is great.

However, on my Galaxy S7 running Android 7.0, the alerts I get appear anywhere between 15 mins to an hour *after* the event has started.

Of course I've checked time zones and daylight saving settings both on the phone and the Calendar app (and on the Google Account too), and all is good there.

Would anyone know what I could do to fix this?

Comment: Google Calendar allows you to change the reminder time either by each event individually, or by defaults set into specific calendars, but there isn't an item to make sure that reminders happen or are directed to a specific device. Your question clearly indicates a lack of communication, and possibly is related to loss of wifi due to inactivity connection loss; this cannot be overcome by Google Calendar, and isn't its concern.

Comment: @wbogacz that not only applies to Google calendar, but to most others as well. But yes, I saw OP asked specifically for that :) Besides, loss of WiFi shouldn't be relevant here once the event has been synchronized. Those alerts are handled locally on the device, and thus should even work in airplane mode.

Comment: While the event resides locally, I believe, but do not know, that the event synchronizes before throwing the reminder. This would ascertain that both the host and the device have the latest (if any) changes, and can record the reminder action. No synchronization until later, results in the reminder action thrown late. This is generally not a problem with a PC, whose connection remains open and active continually, generally by security and network rules, so the reminder action is unimpeded.